# draw html from a graphics object

Tags: blackberry

i want to display html from a graphics object.

```
string htmlText = "<html>......</Html>"
```

i want to know if it is possible to draw html content somehow using the graphics object. I could do it using browserfield, but i do not neeed that.

```
myGraphicsObject.draw.......... or something here
```

any help is welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting one solution here . I dont know, if it will be helpful for you. Using Graphics object you can create mutable objects. then you can modify that image like anything.  i am showing here one example

```
    you can craeate the mutable Bitmap like

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    Graphics c = new Graphics(bmp);
    c.setFont(customFont);
    c.setColor(Color.LIMEGREEN);
    c.drawRect(5, 5, width-10, height-10);

    c.setColor(Color.ROSYBROWN);
    c.setFont(customFont);
    c.drawText("Some text"   , 5, 5);
    c.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    c.setFont(customFont);
    c.drawLine(5, 20, width-10, 20);
```

like this you can draw different things on that Bitmap uing graphics. I think this will help you.
        Feel free to post as useful , if you find it is useful.

Comment: suppose I have some text which has to be underlined(coming from HTML tag). I want it to be parsed and shown as html, currently what looks to me that i Have to "manually" draw a line under the text after finding the concerned tag in the text, which will be really awful.